# Trying to use hashmap to count frequency of words in array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, hashmap

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    HashMap<String,Integer> histogram = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    while ( infile.ready() )
    {   
        String SPACE = " ";
        String [] words = infile.readLine().split(SPACE);

        for (String word : words)
        {
            Integer f = histogram.get(word);
            histogram.put(word,f+1);
        }   
    }
    infile.close();
    printHistogram( histogram );
}
private static void printHistogram( HashMap<String,Integer> hm )
{
    System.out.println(hm);
}
```

I keep getting a NullPointerException for the " histogram.put(word,f+1);" part. why is this?

Comment: What happens if `f` is `null`?

Comment: Also, look at Guava Multiset. It's a similar data structure specifically built for counting the occurrences of items.

Answer (score 11):

This happens because `f` will be null if the value is not found in the map.  Try this, inside the `for` loop.

```
Integer f = histogram.get(word);
if (f == null) {
    histogram.put(word, 1);
} else {
    histogram.put(word, f+1);
}
```

Comment: shoot, I'm mad that I didn't pick that up. it works now, thank you very much!